# How to configure OPTIONS request in CORS to Access-Control-Allow-Origin with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having an issue trying to get a token from my server on an Angular 5 project. My `POST` request is never sent and the server returns `400 Bad Request` and shows the following in the console:

[image: Console Screenshot]

[image: Headers Screenshot]

[image: Response Screenshot]

My understanding is that I need to configure the `OPTIONS` request in CORS to allow the cross-origin request, but I feel like I've tried every solution there is out there without any success.

As far as what I have tried so far, in my `Web.config` I have this:

[image: Web.config Screenshot]

And I enabled CORS globally in my `WebApiConfig.cs`:

[image: WebApiConfig.cs Screenshot]

I even implemented the solution suggested at  https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2012/11/using-cors-with-asp-net-web-api/

Here is the call I am making in my Angular 5 project:

```
userAuthentication(userDetails: LoginUser): Observable<LoginUser> {
var data = "username=" + userDetails.username + "&password=" + userDetails.password + "&grant_type=password";
var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'No-Auth': 'True' });
return this.http.post<LoginUser>(this._baseUrl + 'Token', data, { headers: reqHeader })
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
}
```

When I make the call using POSTMAN, everything runs smoothly and I get my `access_token`.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to resolve this issue. I needed to add `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` with `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`.

I then had to add `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` to my `Startup.cs` file:

[image]

…and remove the `customHeaders` from between the `system.webserver` tags in `Web.config`:

[image]

All is running smoothly now.

Note: It's important to note that when enabling CORS on your `WebApiConfig.cs`, if you have followed the previous steps I have shown, you must enable it like this:

[image]

…and not like this:

[image]

If you do, you will get an error stating your header contains multiple values and therefore will deny your `Origin` access.